# gets() & puts() not declared in scope in dev c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

This is my simple code for a bookshop
There is nothing wrong with the code. I am using DevC++ to run the code and after compling it gives out an error which says 'gets' was not declared in this scope & the same error for puts. Please help me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class Book
{
    char *title,*author,*publisher,ans;
    int price,quant,quant_ent;

    public:
            Book()
            {
        title = new char[50];
        author = new char[50];
        publisher = new char[50];
        price = quant = quant_ent = 0;
            }

        void getdata()
        {
            cout<<"\nEnter The Title";
            gets(title);
            cout<<"\nEnter The Author";
            gets(author);
            cout<<"\nEnter The Publisher";
            gets(publisher);
            cout<<"\nEnter The Price";
            cin>>price;
            cout<<"\nEnter The Quantity";
            cin>>quant;
        }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<setw(15)<<title<<setw(15)<<author<<setw(15)<<publisher<<setw(10)<<quant
            <<setw(10)<<price;
    }

    void search(char search_title[],char search_author[])
    {
        if(strcmpi(author,search_author)==0)
        {
            if(strcmpi(title,search_title)==0)
            {
                cout<<"\nBook Found!";
                cout<<"\nEnter The Quantity: ";
                cin>>quant_ent;
                if(quant_ent <= quant)
                {
                    cout<<"\nThe Title is: ";
                    puts(title);
                    cout<<"\nThe Author is: ";
                    puts(author);
                    cout<<"\nThe Publisher is: ";
                    puts(publisher);
                    cout<<"\nPrice Of Single Copy: "<<price;
                    cout<<"\nTotal Price = "<<price*quant_ent;
                    quant = quant - quant_ent;
                }

                else
                {
                    cout<<"\nSufficient Quantity Not Available!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
Book obj[10];
int i=0,ch;

char author[50],title[50];

for(;;)
{
    cout<<"\n*******MENU********\n1)Enter Details\n2)Buy Book\n3)Display All Books\n4)Exit";
    cin>>ch;

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
            obj[i].getdata();
            i++;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"\nEnter The Authors Name: ";
            gets(author);
            cout<<"\nEnter The Title: ";
            gets(title);
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                obj[j].search(title,author);
            }

            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<setw(15)<<"TITLE"<<setw(15)<<"AUTHOR"<<setw(15)<<"PUBLISHER"<<setw(15)<<"QUANTITY"<<setw(15)<<"PRICE";
            cout<<"\n"<<setw(75)<<"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                cout<<"\n";
                obj[j].display();
            }

        case 4:
            exit(1);
    };
}
}
```

Comment: You're missing an include: `#include <stdio.h>`. That said...why in C++ you're using `gets()`, `puts()` and `char[]` instead of `getline()`, `cout` and `string`?

Comment: Your problem is you had to use them because you started with C-style strings. Move to `std::string` and you won't need C functions because `cin` and `cout` works well with `string`.

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with the code." -- What basis do you have for that claim?

Comment: @Adriano Thanx a lot. I am not much aware of the std::string class. I will surely read about it on the net. But my college computers have Turbo C++, and this namespace thing doesnt seem work on it. So will this std::string work on it? Thanx in advance

Comment: @user237566 Turbo C++ comes from ancient times but yes, if it's not too old then you have std::string class: no more puts()/gets()/char[] all around (well, more or less).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's declared in `stdio.h` (`cstdio` in C++) header and you haven't included it.

But [you shall not use `gets`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) It's a hopelessly broken function. Use `fgets` instead. Even better, ditch the naked pointers to char arrays and use `std::string` class instead.

Comment: But note that `fgets` is not a safer `gets`. [It has different behaviour entirely.](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/social-processes-and-heartbleed-part-1/240167053)